# How to find the orthogonal complement of a given subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

For this question, to find the orthogonal complement for $\operatorname{sp}([1,3,0],[2,1,4])$,do I just take the nullspace $Ax=0$? I am not asking for the answer, I just want to know if I have the right approach.

Comment: You didn't say what $A$ is.

Comment: What is $A $? The given span is a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb {R}^2$. So the orthogonal complement is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthogonal complement is nothing but finding a basis.

$$\mbox{Let us consider} A=Sp\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$A^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 & 0\\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 0\end{bmatrix}_{R_1<->R_2}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 4 & 0\\ 1 & 3 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}_{R_1->R_1\times\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \dfrac { 1 }{ 2 }  & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}_{R_2->R_2-R_1}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \dfrac { 1 }{ 2 }  & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & \dfrac { 5 }{ 2 }  & -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}_{R1->R_1-\frac12R_2}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \dfrac { 1 }{ 2 }  & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -\dfrac { 4 }{ 5 }  & 0 \end{bmatrix}_{R1->R_1-\frac{R_2}{2}}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dfrac { 12 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -\dfrac { 4 }{ 5 }  & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$x_1+\dfrac{12}{5}x_3=0$$
$$x_2-\dfrac45x_3=0$$
$$\mbox{Let $x_3=k$ be any arbitrary constant}$$
$$x_1=-\dfrac{12}{5}k\mbox{ and }x_2=\frac45k$$
$$\mbox{Therefor, the orthogonal complement or the basis}=\begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac { 12 }{ 5 }  \\ \dfrac { 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Why did you change it to $\Bbb R^4$? And also, how come this answer is different from the one in the book? The answer in the book is $sp(12,4,5)$.

Comment: @dg123 The answer in the book and the above answers are same.  I just divided all the elements by $5$. Note that $sp(-12,4,5)=sp\left(-\dfrac{12}{5},\dfrac45,1\right)$

Comment: Alright, they are equivalent to each other because$ sp(-12,4,5) = a[-12,4,5]$ and a can be any real number right

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: Alright, if the question was just sp(2,1,4), would I just dot product (a,b,c) with (2,1,4) and then convert it to into $A^T$ and then row reduce it?

Comment: If you are doing row reduction then no need of dot product. You will directly get the answer with the row reduction.

Comment: But if it's just sp(2,1,4), then you can't really form that into a matrix to do row reduction. How would we do it if it was just sp(2,1,4)?

Comment: You atleast need to two vectors to do either row reduction or dot product.

Comment: so pick two vectors (2,1,4) ane (a,b,c)?

Comment: You cannot do anything if you are given one vector. You need at least two vectors say (2,1,4) and (3,1,0). If you have one vector like (2,1,4) it is not possible to find the orthogonal complement.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal complement is the set of all vectors whose dot product with any vector in your subspace is 0. It's a fact that this is a subspace and it will also be complementary to your original subspace.

In this case that means it will be one dimensional. So all you need to do is find a (nonzero) vector orthogonal to [1,3,0] and [2,1,4], which I trust you know how to do, and then you can describe the orthogonal complement using this.

Answer (score 0):

Take $(a,b,c)$ in the orthogonal complement. Then, since any element in the orthogonal complement must be orthogonal to $W=\langle(1,3,0)(2,1,4)\rangle$, you get this system:

$$(a,b,c) \cdot (1,3,0)= a+3b = 0$$
$$(a,b,c) \cdot (2,1,4)= 2a+b+4c = 0$$

One can see that $(-12,4,5)$ is a solution of the above system. Just take $c=1$ and solve for the remaining unknowns.

Of course, any $\vec{v}=\lambda(-12,4,5)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is also a solution to that system. Since we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\dim W = 2$, we know that the dimension of the orthogonal complement must be $1$ and hence we have fully determined the orthogonal complement, namely:

$$W^{\perp}=\langle (-12,4,5)\rangle$$

Comment: is lamda times (-12,4,5) equivalent to saying the span of (-12,4,5)?

Comment: @dg123   Yup. The span of one vector by definition is the set of all vectors that are obtained by scaling it.

Comment: How do we know that the orthogonal compliment is automatically the span of (-12,4,5)?

Comment: @dg123 The dimension of the ambient space is $3$. The dimension of $W$ is $2$. We know that the dimension of $W^T$ and $W$ must add up to $3$. This means that $W^T$ is one-dimensional and we can span it by just one vector. Is that clear now?

Comment: Yes, this kinda makes sense now. How would the question change if it was just sp(2,1,4)?

Comment: @dg123 Then you had to find "two vectors" that are linearly independent and orthogonal to $(2,1,4)$ because the dimension of the orthogonal complement would've been $2$. For example, $(2,0,-1)$ and $(0,4,-1)$. The key thing to remember in this case is that the two vectors you find this time should be linearly independent to span a two-dimensional subspace. Is it clear?

Comment: So I'd do the dot product of (2,1,4) with an orthogonal vector (a,b,c) and then convert it into the transpose of the matrix and then row-reduce it?

Comment: @dg123 You should solve the system $2a+b+4c=0$. This system has $2$ degrees of freedom. So, fix two of the variables and solve for the third. If $c=1$ and $b=0$, then $a=-2$. If $a=0$ and $c=1$, then $b=-4$. So, I have found two vectors that are orthogonal to my new $W$: $(-2,0,1)$ and $(0,-4,1)$. It now suffices to show that they're linearly independent which can be seen easily. Hence, they are a basis for the orthogonal complement of $W$.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain again why we fix two of the variables?

Comment: @dg123  Your system has two degrees of freedom because we have one equation but three unknowns. The number of unknowns minus the number of equations you have tells you how much freedom you have when finding a solution to the system. Since we have two degrees of freedom, we can cleverly choose two of the variables in a way that simplifies things for us and then solve for the third unknown that is left. It's just a standard linear algebra technique. You need to get yourself comfortable with this stuff.